# Split Monomorphisms and products

Tags: category-theory

This question originates from the answer to this question: [Proof model category chain complexes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1886457/proof-model-category-chain-complexes).

Let $i:A\to B$ be a morphism in an abelian such that $B\cong A\coprod C$ where $\coprod$ denotes the coproduct of $A$ and $C$.

Question: How does this give $B$ the structure of a product with $i$ being the inclusion of $A$ into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly since coproducts are only defined up to isomorphism your requirement *should* be equivalent to saying that the triple $(B,i,j)$, where $i : A\to B$ is the morphism you began and $j : C\to B$ is composite of the coproduct inclusion $C\to A\sqcup C$ with the isomorphism $A\sqcup C\cong B$, is a coproduct. After that the universal property of coproduct produces $p: B\to A$ and $q:B\to C$ such that $pi=1_A$, $pj=0$, $qi=0$ and $qj=1_C$. The universal property of the coproduct then shows that that $ip+jq=1_B$. $B$ together with the morphisms $i,j,p,q$ satisfying the equations mentioned is what is known as a biproduct. I will leave it as an exercise to you show that for such a biproduct the triple $(B,p,q)$ is a product.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you require $B$ to be a coproduct or does this follow from the isomorphism? Given any map $g:A\to H$ I don't see why there is a $p:B\to H$ with $pi=g$.

Comment: Or more precisely: Clearly $B$ is the coproduct as an object because it is determined up to isomorphism, but why is $i$ the inclusion under this iso? Does this hold in general or is this special about the situation linked in my post? I appreciate your help!

Comment: @user360376 No, of course not. What if $i$ was a zero morphism?

Comment: @user360376 On the other hand if $i$ is a split monomorphism, then $i$ is a coproduct inclusion (without any further conditions).

Comment: I see. Can you help me once more? Let $g$ be the left inverse for $i$. I want to show that $i$ is the coproduct inclusion to $B$. So given a map $f_1:A\to X$ I need to find a map $h:B\to X$ such that $hi=f_1$. Here is how I would define $h$: Let $\tilde{h}:A\coprod C\to X$ be the unique map such that $f_1=\tilde{h}\iota_A$. Then define $h=\tilde{h}\iota_A g$ and $h i=f_1$ holds. However I hoped that also $hj=f_2$ for a given map $f_2:C\to X$ with the $j$ of your post, but this does not hold. So how is $(B,i,j)$ a coproduct? Thank you so much!

Comment: Firstly note that according to your definition of $h = f_1 g$ (so that you don't need to talk about $\tilde h$).  Secondly the universal property of a coproduct requires two morphism (i.e. $\tilde h$ is not well defined as is - there may be several morphisms with the property $f_1=\tilde h \iota_A$). Finally I am not sure what you are looking for but here is a correct closely related fact. In an abelian category let $i: A\to B$ be a split monomorphism with right inverse $g$ and let $k : K \to A$ be the kernel of $g$. Then $(B,i,k)$ is a coproduct. Is that what you need?

Comment: I tried to figure out what you mean by a split morphism is a coproduct inclusion. Assume $i:A\to B$ is a split morphism. Then $B$ is a coproduct with respect to what objects?

Comment: $B$ is a coproduct of $A$ and $K$ (where $K$ is the (object part of the) kernel of a left inverse of $i$).

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks a lot for your answers and patience.